# Odoo 8: Calling do_enter_transfer method from another module(quality control)

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

im semi new in odoo programming. Im costumising quality control module. I have issues while calling do_enter_transfer function in my custom button, for calling this function i use server action :

```html
action = {"stock.transfer_details".do_detailed_transfer}

#Button attributes
<button name="transferer_article" type="action"/>
```

On my custom button, i call the action name 

when i click on it, it shows me integrity error :

The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following: - deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it - creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[object with reference : stock_transfer_details - stock.transfer.details]

Comment: When you click on save button do you have this error? If not please put the code fo the method that you are calling?

Comment: Yes i have the same error when i click on save button

Comment: So you have a required field in your model that is not present in the view look for it. You can save a record with missing required field

Comment: That’s what i was thinking but i checked on the form view and all the required fields are there. There are juste two required fields. Im usine one2many field wich call these two required fields : sourceloc_id and destinationloc_id

Comment: What is the type of this field `stock_transfer_details` , is it required and is it in the same model?

Comment: Stock_transfer_details is not a field but a class wish contain the function that i call in my custom button. It is in stock module in wizard folder. No it is not in the same model

Comment: Can anyone help me please for this issues